# How to read AppSetting in HTML page

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a html page in which there is a Link whose address is mentioned in AppSettings tag of web config

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="MyAttribute" value="https://www.google.co.in/" />
</appSettings>
```

Html Code : [i  need to do something like this]

```
 <a href=" <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyAttribute")%> " > fbm.wrdsreports.com</a>
```

Note : Above method does not work.Please be patient i am new to HTML.

Can any one suggest me how to do it.

Comment: What language are you using? VB.Net or C#? If C#, it should be written: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAttribute"]`

Comment: You can only do this in server processed pages, ie. ASPX and the like. HTML pages are (by default) served as static content and not processed by the ASP.NET pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Hi could you please try below..

```
<a href="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("MyAttribute")[0]%>">fbm.wrdsreports.com</a>
```

Comment: -1: it's an HTML page. It's not going to work (unless he configures IIS to pass all HTML pages through ASP.NET, which is probably overkill).

Comment: I _did_ give the reason.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Well OP already suggested he wanted to do something like this only, So I don't think it matter as per OP requirement ,However thanks for suggestion .

Comment: @ Vishal : it Worked ,  @ John : It Worked ..!

Comment: How did it work? You would have to configure IIS to send HTML pages to ASP.NET. Otherwise, there's no way that would work.

Comment: @Sunil John is right sunil, was it a `HTML` page or `aspx` page ?No doubt it worked but in your question you should mention `aspx` page , HTML and aspx both are different, Or may be your IIS is already configured to process HTML pages.

Comment: @JohnSaunders :  yes i guess i did not noticed. it worked in Apsx page not in HTML.